# MySQL Joining Table with Filter

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, join

I'm writing a user-group-system. Here is my database structure:

```
users(id username group_id)
-------- -------- --------
1        gesting  1

groups(id title)
--------- -----
1         Admin

permissions(id value)
-------------- --------------
1              testpermission

user_group_properties
group_id user_id permission_id data
-------- ------- ------------- -------------------------
1        NULL    1             some further information
NULL     1       1             some further information
```

Every user is in a group and every group has one entry in the user_group_properties-table.
Now I want to start at the permissions-table and want to join in the user_group_properties-table. The user-id and the group-id is given.
If the user has an own row in the user_group_properties-table (at least one entry "where user_id = {user_id}", then I want to get this row, otherwise I want to get the row of the group.

In the sample data you can see a permission with id 1. In the user_group_properties-table are two entries with permission_id 1. In the first entry the user_id is null and the group_id not, in the second entry the group_id is null and the user_id not.
If I'm doing a Join-Query now the MySQL-Server will give me the first row, the row where the user-id is null, but I need the row where the user-id is not null if such a row exists. If now row exists where the user-id is null I need the row of the group.

I hope you can help me.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Can you edit your question and provide sample data and desired results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to prioritize the access from `user_group_properties` . . . first if the user exists, then for any groups.  Here is one method:

```
select ugp.*
from user_group_properties ugp
where ugp.user_id = {user_id}
union all
select ugp.*
from user_group_properties ugp join
     users u
     on ugp.group_id = u.group_id and u.id = {user_id}
where not exists (select 1 from user_group_properties ugp2 where ugp2.user_id = {user_id}
```

Comment: Is there a method to get these information over the permission table? I want to use this as the base because I need the information of the permission table too.

Comment: @JanW . . . You can join in the permissions table to the two subqueries.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM   user_group_properties
WHERE  permission_id = 1
AND    (user_id = 1 OR user_id is NULL)
ORDER  BY user_id DESC
LIMIT  1
```